# MySQL join not producing expected results with 'in' function

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join

I have a game_players table like this (other columns omitted for brevity):

```
game_id user_id
1       1
1       3
2       1
2       2
2       4
```

My intention is to show the user that's logged in only the games they're involved in (e.g. user 2 should only see game 2).

The "where 2 in(select game_players.user_id from game_players)" bit doesn't appear to be working, I get a list of all the games - including the ones user 2 isn't involved in.

```
select games.game_id as 'game_id', 
    games.date_game_started as 'date_started', 
    users.username as 'username', 
    users.permanent_id as 'permanent_id', 
    game_players.user_id as 'user_id' 
from games 
    inner join game_players on games.game_id = game_players.game_id
    inner join users on game_players.user_id = users.user_id
where 2 in(select game_players.user_id from game_players) 
and games.game_active = 1 
and game_players.current_turn = 1 
group by(games.game_id) 
order by field(game_players.user_id, 2) desc, 
         games.date_game_started asc
```

Given my test data, I get this result set:

```
game_id date_started        username    permanent_id    user_id 
1       2021-12-15 13:33:17 userc       userc           3
2       2021-12-15 13:35:20 Admin       admin           1
```

I should only be getting the second row, because user 2 is only involved in game 2.

I'll admit that my SQL is a bit rusty, please can you help?

Comment: A group by without any aggregation functions isn't useful. Also add sample data from users and games

Comment: 'where 2 in(select game_players.user_id from game_players) ' - is always true therefore pointless perhaps where  game_players.user_id = 2 is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I simplified/broke it down and found the answer. I think... so far so good on my testing of it.

Needed to change:

```
where 2 in(select game_players.user_id from game_players)
```

to...

```
where game_players.game_id in(select game_id from game_players where user_id = 2)
```